# Laravel Eloquent truncates base64 string

Tags: php, laravel-4, eloquent

I've got a problem with eloquent where it truncates a base64 string being fetched from a mysql database. The column is a mediumblob.

I did a test and fetched the same row directly using PDO and the full length string is returned.

Has anyone had a similar problem?

I also can't see anything in the Database\Eloquent\Model.php that could be causing this.

The code I am using is the standard eloquent "find":

```
Document::find($id);
```

The PDO code that I tested with that returns the full string is:

```
$stmt = $dbh->query("SELECT * FROM documents where uuid = '". $uuid . "' ");
$row = $stmt->fetch();
```

Comment: Please show us your code.

Comment: Have you solved this problem, did my answer help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the following snippet to your MySQL connection config, which by default lives in database.php > connections > mysql.

```
'options' => array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_MAX_BUFFER_SIZE => 16777216)
```

Comment: Hi Dave, apologies for the late reply. That sorted out the problem thank you.